# how to mock a local variable using mockito in java

Tags: java, spring, mockito, powermock, powermockito

```
class Testing{

 @Autowired
 ClassA classa; 

public void test(){
    MyService service = classa.someMethod();
service.getID(); //service is always null on this line
   }
}

ClassA {
public MyService someMethod(){
return Myservice.builder().id(1l).build();
}
}

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
@Builder
@Getter
public class MyService {
    private Long id;
    private Long externalId;
}
```

trying to mock "MyService service" it is always null.
How do we mock it?

MyService is a builder class and the @Builder is from import lombok.Builder; package

Comment: Something like when(classa.someMethod()).thenReturn(<some return value>);

Comment: sorry ...edited my query a bit, have to pass the value got from service to another method.

Comment: Please post complete code for people to be able to help out in this case.

Comment: This is the code...need to write a test case for the test method...

Answer (score 0):

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class Testing{

    @Mock
    MyService service;

    public void test(){
        when(service.getID()).thenReturn(1);
        service.getID()
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add more info to your answer on how this works and why

Comment: did not work for me....Also Myservice is a builder class

Comment: I didn't saw the whole code before. In that case, it will be something like:  

`@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
        class Testing{

        @Mock
        ClassA classa;

        public void test(){
            when(classa.someMethod()).thenReturn(Myservice.builder().id(1l).build());
            MyService service = classa.someMethod();
            service.getID()
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Using Junit4 + Mockito

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ClassATest {
    @Mock
    ClassA classa;

    @Test
    public void test(){
        //Arrange
        MyService service = MyService.builder().id(1l).build();
        when(classa.someMethod()).thenReturn(service);
        
        //Act
        MyService returnedService = classa.someMethod();

        //Assert
        assertEquals(1L, returnedService.getId().longValue());
    }
}
```